# Using roles with spring boot actuator

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to configure the "health" actuator endpoint to provide details only if authenticated user has the ADMIN role.

```
management.security.role: ADMIN
management.security.enabled: true

endpoints:
    health:
        id: health
        sensitive: true
        enabled: true
        time-to-live: 1000
```

The behaviour I'm seeing is that details are provided regardless of whether the authenticated user has the ADMIN role or not, as long as it's authenticated.

This seems to be in line with the [HealthMvcEndpoint](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.2.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/HealthMvcEndpoint.java#L161) implementation which only checks that the principal is not null and is not Anonymous.

Can you please provide some clarifications on how I'm supposed to use roles with actuator? (I only want to restrict access to the sensitive details not the entire endpoint).

- spring boot version: 1.2.4.RELEASE
- spring framework: 4.1.6.RELEASE

Thank you.

Comment: I believe Spring boot doesn't provide such functionality for you. You would have to write your custom implementation using metrics libraries. There's some guidance in Boots manual as well.

Comment: What is then management.security.role property used for? Documentation says it's the "role required to access the management endpoint"

Comment: I'm afraid that restriction is meant for the endpoint. You don't have an option to enable the endpoint and show non-sensitive data using default implementation.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get it. It already does that! It's just that the restriction is not applied as I need: 

Unauthenticated I get:
`{
  "status": "UP",
}`

and if I authenticate, I get 

`{
  "status": "UP",
  "diskSpace": {
    "status": "UP",
    "free": 455234420736,
    "threshold": 10485760
  },
  "mongo": {
    "status": "UP",
    "version": "3.0.4"
  }
}`

This correlates with the documentation: 
"Shows application health information (a simple ‘status’ when accessed over an unauthenticated connection or full message details when authenticated)."